# How do I apply hover over my linked images? (They are icons within a Wordpress post)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I apply hover over my linked images? (They are icons within a Wordpress post)

This is the code created within the Wordpress post.

```
<p>
    <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/meganpolk/?eq=miss&amp;etslf=2961">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-739" src="http://misspsstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SM-Icons_01.png" alt="Miss P's Style on Pinterest" width="72" height="72" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MissPsStyle/">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-740" src="http://misspsstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SM-Icons_02.png" alt="Miss P's Style on Facebook" width="72" height="72" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/missps_style/">
        <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-741" src="http://misspsstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SM-Icons_03.png" alt="Miss P's Style on Instagram" width="72" height="72" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: you forgot add some code ;-)

Comment: Please use the code snippet tool and add the appropriate code (HTML / CSS )

Comment: Sorry. My first time posting. I'm trying my best.

Answer (score 1):

To add a effect to your images that appears when you hover over one of them, simply use CSS's pseudo class `:hover` like below:

```css
img:hover {
  background-color: blue; /** This is just to show how it works. Replace the content of this rule with your own styles */
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/meganpolk/?eq=miss&amp;etslf=2961">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-739" src="http://misspsstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SM-Icons_01.png" alt="Miss P's Style on Pinterest" width="72" height="72" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MissPsStyle/">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-740" src="http://misspsstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SM-Icons_02.png" alt="Miss P's Style on Facebook" width="72" height="72" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/missps_style/">
    <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-741" src="http://misspsstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SM-Icons_03.png" alt="Miss P's Style on Instagram" width="72" height="72" />
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: I've seen this code before when searching, but I don't know exactly where to put it. Do I put it in the Wordpress post code section or do I have to put it somewhere in style.css

Comment: @CarmenWilliams I never worked with Wordpress, but posting the code into style.css should do it.